# Akka: delivery guarantee of messages sent to snapshot store

Tags: akka, persistence, snapshot, reliable-message-delivery

what is the delivery guarantee of messages sent to the snapshotStore, such as `DeleteSnapshot`, `SaveSnapshot` etc?

is it at-least-once or is it at-most-once? 
In other words, if I call `SaveSnapshot()`, am I guaranteed to receive either `SaveSnapshotSuccess/Failure` or will I receive them only if snapshot actually receives them and accept or reject them?

Answer (score 1):

From inspecting the source code for the latest version of `SnapshotStore.scala`, it looks like the trait only extends `Actor` and `ActorLogging`, so message delivery semantics may just be at most once:

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/9d2bec7f232b628cc087231af75e457072823e61/akka-persistence/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/snapshot/SnapshotStore.scala